# params is empty when i call Post method on Grails

Tags: web-services, grails

i'm writing webservices for my application.
my problem is that when i call it using GET method it works , but when i use the POST method params doesn't contains ant of my parameters:

when i call using GET , this is the content of params :

```
params : [username:azerty, test:test, param2:param2, action:editProfile, controller:userWebService]
```

when i call using POST, this is the content of params :

```
params : [action:editProfile, controller:userWebService]
```

EDIT :

```
/* user controller */
"/service/$action?"(controller: "userWebService", parseRequest: true)
```

in **UserWebServiceController**

```
....
static allowedMethods = [editProfile:['POST', 'GET']]
....
def editProfile(){

    println "params : "+ params
....
}
```

to test i'm using REST console plugin in chrome

[image]

Comment: How does the `UrlMapping` look like?

Comment: Can you share the code that do the post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params` are not sent as a query string in `POST` requests unlike `GET`. The parameter strings has to be embedded in the request body in case of `POST` request.

Use `content-type`: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

and in the `request-body` use
`username=azerty&test=test`

You should be able to see the parameters in `params` inside controller.

[image]

You should be able to see
`params : [age:25, name:Hamila, action:editProfile, controller:userWebService]`

Did I make you look younger in the test? :)

Comment: thank you @dmahapatro , it works now :) , no you maked me older :p i'm 24 :p , thanks again